# winforms, form has been shown, event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I need to run certain code each time after form has been shown by from.Show(). I tried form_Activated(), form_Loaded(), form.Shown() ... nothing works how I want, it only runs once, the first time.
Is there a simple way how to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own method for showing form and throwing event in him.

```
public event EventHandler ShownEx;

public void ShowEx()
{
    Show();
    OnShownEx();
}

private void OnShownEx()
{
    var eventHandler = ShownEx;
    if (eventHandler != null)
        eventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either override `OnVisibleChanged` method of your form or hook `VisibleChanged` event

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what you are trying to achieve but the shown event is the last of the events,  according to MSDN, when displaying a form.

I had the same problem with a form once. I don't really remember what I did at the time  but out of the top of my head I think I saved all the data I had in the hidden form and displayed a new one every time.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com, Form.Shown Event, The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed ... I need it run every time a form is displayed. It seems that I have to write my own event handler to achieve this ... sadly

Comment: Are you closing it and re displaying it;

Comment: Hide(), either by user or by timer, and then Show() again ...